# change options of tabulator table dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, tabulator

I am using tabulator in my Angular app to display some data. I have a parent component and a child component that displays 2 different tabulator tables using angular mat-tab. The tabulator tables are declared within the child component. I have an edit button on the parent component. Initially, the editMode is false but the on clicking the button, it is set to true.

Thus, initially while setting up the tabulator table I have set the movableRows and movableColumns options to false, however when the editMode is set to true I want to add a new column that serves as a row handle, the row context menus should be visible only in edit mode and also the rows and columns should become moveable.

Write now I am passing a property to the child component and here is the child component code-

```
ngOnChanges(simpleChanges: SimpleChanges): void {

    if (simpleChanges?.isEditMode) {

      if (this.tabulatorTable) {
        this.tabulatorTable.destroy();
      }
      this.movableRows = simpleChanges.isEditMode.currentValue;
      this.movableColumns = simpleChanges.isEditMode.currentValue;
      this.initializeTable(this.highlightRows, this.rowValidation); // this initailizes the tabulator table
    }
  }
```

The thing is the above code slows down the tabulator component significantly when I am in edit mode and switch tabs between the 2 components. Is there any other way I can achieve the desired functionality ?